# Going reusable with data attributes and jquery

Tags: javascript, custom-data-attribute, bootstrap-typeahead

I have many Bootstrap Type-ahead attached to my text-box. 
I was using there id to select then and attach typeahead.

Sample

```
$("#SireTag").typeahead({
    source: function (query, process) {

        $.ajax({

            url: '/Bull/GetSireTag',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'query=' + query,
            dataType: 'JSON',
                async: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);

                    process(data);
                }

            });
        }

    });
```

Now i decided to make it more readable and short by using a single java-script code to attach type ahead to all my text-boxes.

```
<input data-typeahead-url="/Bull/GetSireTag" id="SireTag" name="SireTag" type="text" value="">
```

New Javascript

```
 $('*[data-typeahead-url]')
        .each(function () {
            alert(this);
            $(this).typeahead({
                source: function (query, process) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url:  $(this).data("typeahead-url"),
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: 'query=' + query,
                        dataType: 'JSON',
                        async: true,
                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log(data);

                            process(data);
                        }
                    })
                }
            });

        });
```

But its not working i am not so proficient with java-script anyone now whats wrong.
I tried developers tool ajax request is not made.

Comment: i think `data: 'query=' + query,` must be in json format

Comment: `data: {query:'query='+query}`  you must close using `;` ie `url:  $(this).data("typeahead-url");,`

Answer (score 1):

$('*[data-autocomplete-url]') doesn't select your elements because you're using data-typeahead-url.

Comment: Don't worry about it - I'm sure everyone here has made far worse mistakes!

Comment: Are you getting the alert pop-up? If so, try switching to
   url: $(this).attr("data-typeahead-url"),

Comment: If you're not getting the alert pop-up, try removing the * from your jQuery selector, i.e. $('[data-typeahead-url]')

Answer (score 0):

You need to `return` the ajax result to the `source`, also don't use `alert()` to debug, use `console.log()` instead:

```
$('input[data-typeahead-url]').each(function () {
    $(this).typeahead({
        source: function (query, process) {
            return $.ajax({
                url:  $(this).data("typeahead-url"),
                type: 'POST',
                data: { query: query },
                dataType: 'json',
                async: true,
                success: function (resp) {
                    console.log(resp);

                    return process(resp);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

$('*[data-typeahead-url]')
 .each(function () {

```
 var url = $(this).data("typeahead-url");

 $(this).typeahead({
     source: function (query, process) {
         $.ajax({
             url: url,
             type: 'POST',
             data: 'query=' + query,
             dataType: 'JSON',
             async: true,
             success: function (data) {
                 console.log(data);

                 process(data);
             }
         })
     }
 });
```

});

Problem: The code was making ajax request but to the same address.
Diagnose: I tried `log($(this).data("typeahead-url");)`  which gave desired output.
Solution: I created and stored the Url the used it as a parameter in ajax call

```
var url = $(this).data("typeahead-url");
```

Hope this help.